# NullPointerException invoking removeFromArray in ViewGroup.java:3528

Tags: android, view, frameworks, nullpointerexception

### please help to solve this strange problem:

```
source code:

if(view != null && view.getParent() != null) {
    ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
}
```

---

as you can see, view and view.getParent() can not be null invoking removeView,
but here's the exception we got:

---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeFromArray(ViewGroup.java:3528)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3726)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3690)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3622)
    at xxxx.removeView(yyyy.java:zzzz) // here's code above
```

---

### and here is related code in ViewGroup.java:

```
private void removeFromArray(int index) {
    final View[] children = mChildren;
    if (!(mTransitioningViews != null && mTransitioningViews.contains(children[index]))) {
        children[index].mParent = null;  // !!!! ViewGroup.java:3528
    }
```

index corresponds to a child view, so children[index] should be "view" in our code, and mParent should be "view.getParent()", so why here throwed a NullPointerException?

---

### overall code:

```
if(view != null && view.getParent() != null) {
    ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view);
}

public void removeView(View view) {
    removeViewInternal(view);
}

private void removeViewInternal(View view) {
    final int index = indexOfChild(view);
    if (index >= 0) {
        removeViewInternal(index, view);
    }
}

public int indexOfChild(View child) {
    final int count = mChildrenCount;
    final View[] children = mChildren;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (children[i] == child) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private void removeViewInternal(int index, View view) {
    ......
    removeFromArray(index);
}

private void removeFromArray(int index) {
    final View[] children = mChildren;
    if (!(mTransitioningViews != null && mTransitioningViews.contains(children[index]))) {
        children[index].mParent = null;  // !!!! ViewGroup.java:3528
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't put null check for View[] children. In Array of Object type, by default each index location is initialized with null value.

```
View[] children = new View[10]; //Here Array is not null. but all elements inside it are null

for(int i=0;i<children.length;i++){
    System.out.println(children[i] == null); //certainly true
}

//proper initialization
for(int i=0;i<children.length;i++){
    children[i] = new View();
}
```

Comment: index come from this method: public int getChildIndex(View child) { return mChildren.indexOf(child); }, and index>0, so I think not children[index] but mParent is null

Comment: @samhunter, did you check that children[index] is not null. It could be possible that Array has null objects and indexOf(null) can return index, since array has null object.

Comment: thanks for your kindly help, please check the question updated, I write all related code below "overall code", I think it can't be null